# failure to execute dotnet core site using framework 4.6.1 on azure

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-mvc-5, azure-web-app-service, .net-core

I get this error in the output log file.
There is also a warning on the project.json file indicating that version >4.3.0 was expected for system.runtime, but the build is getting version 4.0.20.0

> Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime`

I have installed system.runtime using nuget `install-package system.runtime.`

My `project.json` framework section looks like this

```
  "frameworks": {
    "net461": {
      "dependencies": {
        "Ignite.Data": {
          "target": "project"
        }
      },
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Runtime.Serialization": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  },
```

The stdout logfile on Azure (obtained via FTP) reads thusly

```
Application startup exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Runtime, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.DefaultAssemblyPartDiscoveryProvider.DiscoverAssemblyParts(String entryPointAssemblyName)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.GetApplicationPartManager(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.MvcServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvc(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 setupAction)
   at Ignite.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in C:\Projects\Github\Ignite\Ignite.Web\Startup.cs:line 83
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Hosting environment: Production
Content root path: D:\home\site\wwwroot
Now listening on: http://localhost:1942
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
```

Azure provides this wonderfully descriptive assistance :-)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are running into a known issue: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/1046. I talked to the .NET experts, and their response is that this will be fixed in 1.1.1 (which is not too far out).

Comment: this looks like it might be a different issue - the issue references `system.net.http` whereas my issue is with `system.runtime`

Comment: I'm not sure, it could be different flavors of same root issue. 1.1.1 should be out on Tuesday, so if you can wait till then, we'll be settled.

Comment: thanks, confirmed this today, 1.1.1 solves the problem. It took a lot of work to get all the dotnet tools in a row, but it's working perfectly, and EF6 (whew!) is working as it should against azure sql v12

Comment: Great, glad to hear!